# Error: Cannot read property 'requestPhoneNumber' of null from react-native-sms-retriever

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to auto detect phone number from user device in react native and I am trying to use the package react-native-sms-retriever(1.1.1).

I have given permisson using:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
```

and

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS!,
        {
          title: 'App Phone Permission',
          message: 'App needs access to your phone ',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      )

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('User granted permisson to phone')
      } else {
        console.log('User denied permission to phone')
      }
```

To use the library, first I imported like this:
`import SmsRetriever from 'react-native-sms-retriever'`

and created a function:

```
  const _onPhoneNumberPressed = async () => {
    try {
      const phoneNumber = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();
      console.log("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
   };
```

But whenever the function is called, the following error appears:
[image: error image in emulator]

I have cleared node_modules and run `npm i` but still having the same issue.

How can I resolve this so as to get a dialog box containing the phone number of user?

Comment: @SathishSaminathan yes, i was not importing library properly